# Matlab Create MD5 Checksum for Variables

Tags: matlab, md5, checksum

For debugging, i wish to compare several objects, and create some unique ID for each them, and according its contents and structure, the ID should be equal. Is there any existing function for doing this?

For example if an object is an structure:

```
S:
 S.a1 = 1
 S.a2 = 2
 S.b1 = 3
   S.b11 = 4
   S.b12 = 5
 S.c1 = 6
```

My current choice is copying it to the disk and calculate a MD5 64-bit checksum, which do not work because this hash depends on the modified date of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is mentioned [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3314-hash-function-for-matlab-struct). `DataHash` function is that solution:

```
function H = DataHash(Data)
Engine = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5');
H = CoreHash(Data, Engine);
H = sprintf('%.2x', H);   % To hex string


function H = CoreHash(Data, Engine)
% Consider the type of empty arrays:
S = [class(Data), sprintf('%d ', size(Data))];
Engine.update(typecast(uint16(S(:)), 'uint8'));
H = double(typecast(Engine.digest, 'uint8'));
if isa(Data, 'struct')
   n = numel(Data);
   if n == 1  % Scalar struct:
      F = sort(fieldnames(Data));  % ignore order of fields
      for iField = 1:length(F)
         H = bitxor(H, CoreHash(Data.(F{iField}), Engine));
      end
   else  % Struct array:
      for iS = 1:n
         H = bitxor(H, CoreHash(Data(iS), Engine));
      end
   end
elseif isempty(Data)
   % No further actions needed
elseif isnumeric(Data)
   Engine.update(typecast(Data(:), 'uint8'));
   H = bitxor(H, double(typecast(Engine.digest, 'uint8')));
elseif ischar(Data)  % Silly TYPECAST cannot handle CHAR
   Engine.update(typecast(uint16(Data(:)), 'uint8'));
   H = bitxor(H, double(typecast(Engine.digest, 'uint8')));
elseif iscell(Data)
   for iS = 1:numel(Data)
      H = bitxor(H, CoreHash(Data{iS}, Engine));
   end
elseif islogical(Data)
   Engine.update(typecast(uint8(Data(:)), 'uint8'));
   H = bitxor(H, double(typecast(Engine.digest, 'uint8')));
elseif isa(Data, 'function_handle')
   H = bitxor(H, CoreHash(functions(Data), Engine));
else
   warning(['Type of variable not considered: ', class(Data)]);
end
```

Also, you can find the complete version of the code [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash).

Comment: That was exactly the solution i wanted to have. I already implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution than @OmG 's answer, that relies on a little bit of undocumented functionality:

```
function str = hash(in)

% Get a bytestream from the input. Note that this calls saveobj.
inbs = getByteStreamFromArray(in);

% Create hash using Java Security Message Digest.
md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA1');
md.update(inbs);

% Convert to uint8.
d = typecast(md.digest, 'uint8');

% Convert to a hex string.
str = dec2hex(d)';
str = lower(str(:)');
```

The undocumented function `getByteStreamFromArray` returns the byte stream that would be written to disk if you were to call the `save -v7` command on the variable. It works for any variable that is less than 2GB in size, including not only the built-in types (numeric, logical, struct, cell etc.) covered by @OmG 's `CoreHash`, but also built-in and user-defined classes as well.

Note that `getByteStreamFromArray` calls `saveobj`, so it will ignore `Transient` properties - this is almost certainly a good thing for hashing as well as saving.

PS In either solution, SHA1 is probably better than MD5.